# HTML5 player_loc in video sitemaps?

Tags: html5-video, sitemap

I'm trying to create an XML sitemap using Google's video extension to the Sitemap Protocol (explained here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80472?hl=en ). All the examples of the `<player_loc>` tag in this document use SWF files. Will Google recognized `<player_loc>` tag with an HTML5 player? Are there any examples of sites doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify at least one of `video:player_loc` OR `video:content_loc`.
So you can choose to omit `video:player_loc` and just point to the actual video media file using `video:content_loc`.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/sitemaps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping NOT to directly expose my media, but if the answer is simply "no" that's helpful information :-)

Comment: I cannot affirm that it is not possible.  But with html5  the player is part of the browser, so I suppose that's why you won't find a location of the player.   The only thing I am really sure of is that my sitemaps that only use video:content_loc are correctly processed by Google.

Comment: That's been my experience too...never hurts to ask! Thanks.